# With ueye_cam, no image published, rqt_image_view crashes

Tags: ros, rqt-image-view, ueye, ueye-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not yet succesful in using [ueye_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/ueye_cam) at all. Issues I'm facing are:

- Out of a few .launch files available, I don't know which one to use for what cases.
- I rarely see the image `topics` published so far. On `ueye`'s GUI that's provided by the seller the cameras are connected and I can see the images via its viewer too.
- `rqt_image_view` crashes when I choose to show `image_raw`. Log snippets is below ([more lengthy log](http://pastebin.com/Km2zVU0N)):

```
    what():  Image is wrongly formed: step != width * byte_depth * num_channels  or  4800 != 640 * 1 * 3

    [ERROR] [1383131645.310434350]: Failed to acquire image from UEye camera 'slave2' (IS_TIMED_OUT)
    [ERROR] [1383131645.322152805]: Compressed Depth Image Transport - Compression requires single-channel 32bit-floating point or 16bit raw depth images (input format is: rgb8).
    [ERROR] [1383131645.322248342]: cv_bridge exception: 'Image is wrongly formed: step != width * byte_depth * 


- Had to patch `CMakeLists.txt` in order to pass `catkin_make` like this (not sure if this is correct though):
```

```
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall")
```

(I just favored over [ueye](http://wiki.ros.org/ueye) package, with which some people reported error but I'm not really sure. I might give a shot to it too.)

@anqixu I think you're the developer. I appreciate a lot if you could help me out.

Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Groovy

---

**Update**-1) @anqixu Thanks for immediate response. The output of `roslaunch ueye_cam rgb8.launch` is posted [here](http://pastebin.com/s20hw8Lv).

Also, rostopic:

```
$ rostopic hz /UI122xLE_C/image_raw
subscribed to [/UI122xLE_C/image_raw]
average rate: 30.883
    min: 0.017s max: 0.043s std dev: 0.00510s window: 27
average rate: 30.353
    min: 0.017s max: 0.043s std dev: 0.00454s window: 57
```

Still, choosing `UI122xLE_C/image_raw` on `rqt_image_view` crashes with the same error I cited above.

---

**Update**-2) Using the latest commit,

```
$ rostopic hz /UI122xLE_C/image_raw
WARNING: topic [/UI122xLE_C/image_raw] does not appear to be published yet
$ rostopic list
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/nodelet_manager/bond
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/ueye_cam_nodelet/parameter_descriptions
/ueye_cam_nodelet/parameter_updates
```

By the way `uEye Camera Manager` v1.7.2 says the model of the camera is `UI155xSE-C`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96121/with-ueye_cam,-no-image-published,-rqt_image_view-crashes/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-10-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) on 2013-11-08**:
Re. Update-2): The latest commit changed the topic name to /camera/image_raw. You need to manually edit the launch file if you would to use a different camera namespace.

Also, the extended log (pastebin.com/Km2zVU0N) shows you running master_slaves_rgb8.launch. Try rgb8.launch instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I would need to know a bit more info before I can help you out. Please try running rgb8.launch, [IMPORTANT!] connect to the image topic (e.g. by running "rostopic hz /UI122xLE_C/image_raw" on a separate terminal), wait for ~5 sec, and paste the entire output of the roslaunch (e.g. on pastebin.com).

Also, thank you for reporting the c++11 flag compile error; I eagerly upgraded to g++4.7, which supports c++11, and forgot to use the backward-compatible c++0x flag instead.

**Edit:** the extended log (pastebin.com/Km2zVU0N) shows execution log from running master_slaves_rgb8.launch. In this particular case, only slave2 had a camera connected, and it was configured (in the launch file, see "ext_trigger_mode") to be externally triggered. Assuming that nothing is wired to the camera, then it will spit out garbage images at a unpredictable rate. Please consider using rgb8.launch or bayer_rggb_image_proc.launch for single-camera usage.

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2